# flutter align listview to the left

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, mobile

Hello I am trying to align to the left a ListView widget, this is the piece of code:

```
Column(children: [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => _removeOptionForm(variantList),
            child: Text("remove option")),
      ),
      Row(children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
                height: 50.0,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: optionFormValueList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return optionFormValueList[index];
                    })),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _optionNameController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autocorrect: false,
```

The ListView stays always to the right, even if I wrapped it on a Container and the last one on a Column.

Comment: try adding crossAxesAlignment to your Column

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: can you make the mainaxisalignment to start for the row

Answer (score 1):

Create Listview builder like this

return ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: data!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) => **Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,**